# Detect end of email

Tags: php, email

Am writing a code in php. I get emails to parse in my app. I need to detect end of email, like if you reply any email on yahoo, email body and response both comes in inbox. In this response i only need to get the reply part .

Similarly there are long signatures at end of email like name, address and some notes. I don't need them . I just need the response part . How an this be achieved ???

Comment: Hmm that's going to be difficult.  Signatures are usually denoted by `-- ` on a line by itself (2 hyphens and a space) but that's not universal.

Comment: Are you using a database to store the emails? I don't know... maybe if you split the email apart using line breaks, and then compare each piece to what's in your database, and if the first 150 characters match, then you cut that part out. But I don't know about cutting the signature out.

Comment: There are a couple of answers to this issue for other languages. The thing is it's pretty hard to do. Looking for known text works best but also look for as many reply areas such as on ... X wrote: finally > can also be found to mark old messages. We've been writing something at Cloudmailin for a while but it's hard to catch everything. I'd take the advice from as many replies as possible and combine them all

Answer (score 0):

The only way you are going to do this is by starting and ending the content of the email with the same "known" text ... ie something you have placed there and you can search for.